# Can connect to EC2 as ubuntu user but not as the user i created

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I created a new ebs backed EC2-instance and the necessary key-pair. Now I am able to connect to the instance as ubuntu user. Once i did that I created another user and added it to the sudoers list but I am unable to connect to the instance as the new user I created.

I get the following error. I am using the same key to connect with the new user i created. Can somebody help me. Am I missing something here?

```
Permission denied (publickey)"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay I think i figured it out.

The first technique is to login by password. The idea is to login as the ubuntu user or root user and go to /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and turn the PasswordAuthentication to yes and run
/etc/init.d/ssh reload

If you try to connect now you ec2 allows you to log with the password of the user that was created. Though this is not really secure.

Second is you create a key-pair and copy the id-rsa.pub file and move it to the /home/new-user/.ssh/authorized_keys file and change permissions to 600 and assign to the appropriate user(new-user in this case).

I found this to be amazingly useful
http://blog.taggesell.de/index.php?/archives/73-Managing-Amazon-EC2-SSH-login-and-protecting-your-instances.html

Answer (score 0):

SSH is very picky about the directory and file permissions. Make sure that:

1. The directory /home/username/.ssh has permission "700" and is owned by the user (not root!)
2. The /home/username/ssh/authorized_keys has permission "600" and is owned by the user

Copy your public key into the authorized_keys file.

```
sudo chown -R username:username /home/username/.ssh
sudo chmod 0700 /home/username/.ssh
sudo chmod 0600 /home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

You can do all that as a root user. There is no need to allow temporarily in /etc/ssh/ssh_config to passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Sid, I did what you mentioned but I still got the same error

> The first technique is to login by password. ...

It took a reboot to get it to work. (Just in case anyone else wants this insecure method to work) The public key method is a major pain to make it work with remote desktop apps